# Google-like Search query spliting Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have search query

```
string input = "FirstName=\"xy z\" LastName=\"Huber\"";
```

would like to use Regex to split it

I would like to have a string array with the following tokens:

```
FirstName=\"xy z\"
LastName=\"Huber\"
```

As you can see, the tokens preserve the spaces with in double quotes

my regex

> ("[^"]+"|\w+)\s*

nearly not want I want..need to fix more it gets

> FirstName= \"xy z\"  LastName = \"Huber\"

Comment: OK, so what have you tried yourself?

Comment: my regex <br/>
("[^"]+"|\w+)\s* <br/>
nearly not want I want..need to fix more
it gets <br/>
FirstName= <br/>
\"xy z\" <br/>
LastName <br/>
\"Huber\" <br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering I4V's answer to match the OP requirements

It seems the OP wants the strings  `FirstName=\"xy z\"` and `LastName=\"Huber\"` rather than a key value pair so the solution is to simply use the matches from I4V regex.

```
string input = "FirstName=\"xy z\" LastName=\"Huber\"";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+?)=\""(.+?)\""")
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

This will give you a string array of the values.

*EDIT* For the specific case asked by OP

```
string input = "FirstName=\"xy z\" LastName=\"Huber\"";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s\""]+(?:\"".*?\"")?")
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: I want to explain more detail

string input = "FirstName=\"xy z\" LastName=\"Huber\" FirstName=Micheal Kimmer";



would like to use Regex to split it As u can see split happens at empty space..if there space is in between double quotation then no split

I would like to have a string array with the following tokens:

-------FirstName=\"xy z\"------
-------LastName=\"Huber\"------
-------FirstName=Micheal-------
-------Kimer----------
Iam very new to this forum..composing really painful "--------" just to indicate different lines

SORRY 4 TROUBLE

Comment: Perfect what i was searching for
THANKS a LOT Bob ..
saved my day...:)